# How to split a dynamically created string separated by comma and put in nextline in dynamically created table td?

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

I have a dynamically created table, from database I fetch a sting joined with comma like `b.common = cmn1,cmn2,cmn3`.

Now need to split with comma and need to put in a new line (need to put with in same td) in dynamically created table td.

```
 if(b.gender_specific == 'N')
    {
    if(b.common != '' || b.common  != null  ){  
       var cm_val = (b.common.split(",").join("\n"));
       $('.patient_tests').append('<tr style=text-align:left id = "trid" class = "trid"><td><input type = "checkbox" name = "resulted_id[]" class = "resulted_id" value = '+b.smpl_dtid+'></td><td width = "15%">'+i+'</td><td width = "25%">'+b.test_name+'</td><td><input type ="text" name = "fnd_value[]" class = "form-control text-right fnd_value" id = "fnd_value" ><td>'+cm_val+'</td></tr>');
    }
```

With this I can split and make an alert. Still when I use it in `td` it shows like  cmn1 cmn2 cmn3.

how to put this as shown below in same td?

```
cmn1
cmn2
cmn3
```

Comment: try to use <br> instead of \n

Comment: Yeah.. i did still no use..

Comment: @Vicmathur  thanks for your time..Finally i made it

Comment: ("<br>") if you use like this it will taken as string you have to add tag in between string cmn1 and 2 and 3

Comment: Yes.. see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

var cm_val = (b.common.split(",").join("<br>"));